# Why surface fitting is not working in logarithmic domain?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, curve-fitting

Let's have a corrupted Image C, Bias profile, B and True Image A. So if we can define a model,

C = A * B;

We can get the original Image back as,

A = C / B;

in the log domain,

log A = log C - log B.

Now let's say, I have true image, A and I am introducing the bias B and I am getting the corrupted image C. Now I can correct this biased Image, C using the polynomial regression. I will fit the surface once I convert the corrupted image C in the log domain, and I can subtract the bias profile from it as shown above. After the subtraction, I don't need to apply exp(log C - log B) as obvious. Onlu normalization is needed to get [0 255] range.

Algorithm:

- Original Image without any bias field is introduced with the polynomial profile, which results in an image having non-uniform illumination.
- Biased image is converted in log domain and surface is approximated using polynomial fit
- approximated surface is subtracted from the Biased image which results in original image back with no bias fields.(Ideally).
- measure RMSE between approximated surface and introduced polynomial field in step 1. Measure RMSE between the Biased Image and the image we get back at the end after subtraction.

Code:

```
clear;clc;close all;

%read the image, on which profile is to be generated
I = ones(300);
I = padarray(I,[20,20],'both','symmetric'); % padding 

%%
%creating a bias profile using polynomial modeling
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:size(I,1),1:size(I,2));
profile = -2.5.*x.^3 - 2.5.* y.^3 + 0.25 .*(x.* y.^2) - 0.3*( x.^2 .* y ) -   0.5.* x .* y - x + y  - 2.5*( x.^2) - y.^2 + 0.5 .* x .*y + 1;

% come to scale [0 1] 
profile = profile - min(profile(:));
profile = profile / max(profile(:));
figure,imshow(profile,[]); %introduced bias profile


%% corrupt the image 
biasedImage = (I .* profile);
figure,imshow(biasedImage,[]); %biased Image


cImage = log(biasedImage+1);% conversion to log domain/ +1 is needed to avoid infinite values in case of 0 intensty values in corrupted image.

%% forming the input for prediction of surface
colorChannel = cImage;
rows = size(colorChannel, 1);
columns = size(colorChannel, 2);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:columns, 1:rows);
z = colorChannel;
x1d = reshape(X, numel(X), 1);
y1d = reshape(Y, numel(Y), 1);
z1d = double(reshape(z, numel(z), 1)); %dependent variables
x = [x1d y1d]; % two regressors

%% surface fitting
m = 3; %define the order of polynomial
p = polyfitn(x,z1d,m); %prediction step
zg = polyvaln(p, x);

modeledColorChannel = reshape(zg, [rows columns]); % predicted surface

 %modeledColorChannel = exp(modeledColorChannel)-1; if we use this step then       the step below will be division instead of subtraction
 %f = biasedImage./ modeledColorChannel; Same as the step below but as we are using exponential, it will be devision.

%% correction
f  = cImage- modeledColorChannel; %getting the original image back. 


%grayImage = f(21:end-20,21:end-20);
%modeledColorChannel = modeledColorChannel(21:end-20,21:end-20); %to remove  the padding

figure,imshow(f,[]);
figure,imshow(modeledColorChannel,[]);


%% measure the RMSE for image
y = (I - f);
RMSE = sqrt(mean(y(:).^2));
disp(RMSE);

% RMSE for profile
z = (modeledColorChannel - profile);
RMSE = sqrt(mean(z(:).^2));
disp(RMSE);
```

Results:

In case of: f  = cImage- modeledColorChannel

1.0000

0.2127

Corrected Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bobsN.jpg)

In case of division: f = cImage ./ modeledColorChannel (although it is not correct as per theory.)

0.0190

0.2127

Corrected Image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO6Sz.jpg)

Now, the question is: I am getting lower RMSE value at the end if I do division in the log domain instead of subtraction as I am doing here(See **%% correction** section). How does it possible to have higher RMSE for subtraction where it is theoriticaly correct? As per my understanding if I keep all of my calculation in log domain image division will become image subtraction.It is obvious if you run the code and see the image f at the end of the correction for division and subtraction in log domain.

Note: In both the cases, RMSE between the introduced and perceived profile is same as I am doing my estimation in log domain in both the cases.Either image division or in image subtraction.

See this for polyfitn tool box.
www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34765-polyfitn

Comment: `A = C / B;` is not `log A=log C/ log B`

Comment: Yes it is not. that's why I am doing f = cImage - modeledColorChannel which executes the step log A = log C - log B. and that is my question why I am getting less RMSE for division instead of subtraction. let me know if I get you wrong. @AnderBiguri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me add to the answer to my question as I found my mistake, in case anybody faces same issue in future.

Mistake 1: After the subtraction, I don't need to apply exp(log C - log B) as obvious. Only normalisation is needed to get [0 255] range.

My intuition was, I don't need to apply exp() to get the original values back. But in fact I have to apply exp(). Log-log on LHS and RHS never cancels each other.

if log(A) = log(B), to get the values of A back I need A = exp(log(B)).

Mistake 2: In log domain, I subtract two images so I do not have to face infinity problem in the log domain, we usually face in case of division.

So simply while converting image in log domain, I could just do,

```
cImage = log(biasedImage);
```

instead of,

```
cImage = log(biasedImage+1);
```

Here, adding +1 is creating the unwanted blur in the images because in estimation while predicting surface it will push the surface to high values in the dark areas.